# Getting the output in a sequence order in sql

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a column col1,col2 in Table A col3 can be in Table or it can be a virtual column, this is the data that i have.

```
COL1    COL2
0         1
3         1
5         1
7         1
8         1
10        1
0         2
21        2
23        2
25        2
26        2
28        2
0         3
39        3
0         4
```

How can i get My expected manipulated data by generating(1,2,3..) dynamically like this in a column when ever there is change of value in column 2 there will be 0 in COL1 then the sequence should start all from (1,2..):-

```
   COL1    COL2    COL3
    0        1       0
    3        1       1
    5        1       2
    7        1       3
    8        1       4
    10       1       5
    0        2       0
    21       2       1
    23       2       2
    25       2       3
    26       2       4
    28       2       5
    0        3       0
    39       3       1
    0        4       0
```

-- DDL :-

```
Create table TEST_A
(
COL1 number,
COL2 number
);

-- DML:-
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (0,1  );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (3,1  );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (5,1  );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (7,1  );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (8,1  );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (10,1 );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (0,2  );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (17,2 );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (0,3  )   ;
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (21,3 );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (23,3 );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (25,3 );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (26,3 );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (28,3 );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (0,4  )   ;
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (39,4 );
Insert into TEST_A (COL1,COL2) values (0,5  )   ;
commit;
```

Comment: Tim has already provided the best answer. A question though: is it guaranteed that, for every fixed value in COL2, the corresponding values in COL1 will always be distinct? If not, what is the desired result? What Tim provided is one of the options; the other two can be achieved using the RANK() or DENSE_RANK() functions instead of ROW_NUMBER. If the COL1 values are always distinct for every fixed value in COL2, all three functions will produce the same outcome. (Yet another option in the case of "ties" is to "break the tie" by values in another column.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Oracle `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function here.  But since you want to start your row numbers at zero, subtract one, since `ROW_NUMBER()` is one-based by default.

```
select
    COL1,
    COL2,
    row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col2) - 1 as col3
from TEST_A
```